# Convert string to json in jq

Tags: json, command-line, jq

### Background

I have a json file that contains a string of json within an object:

```
{
    "requestType": "POST",
    "response": {
        "size": 78,
        "text": "{\"recordID\":123, \"title\":\"Hello World\", \"content\":\"Lorem ipsum...\"}"
    }
}
```

I need to interperet the contents of the `.response.text` string as json using the json command line interpereter, [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

When I run this command:

```
jq '.response.text | @json'
```

Output: `"\"{\\\"recordID\\\":123, \\\"title\\\":\\\"Hello World\\\", \\\"content\\\":\\\"Lorem ipsum...\\\"}\""`

I get some weird escaped json string instead of json that I can access via something like this: `.response.text | @json | .recordID`.

I realize that the `@json` function will take json and output a json escaped string, so there must be another way, but `@text` doesn't seem to do anything.

### Question

Is there some way to convert a string of escaped json to actual json that I can parse with a command such as this: `jq '.response.text | @json | .title'` and get this output: `"Hello World"`?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Use [`fromjson`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#convert-to-from-json).

It parses a string to its appropriate json value.  `tojson` (and `@json`) goes the other way around and takes a json value and converts it to a string.

So you could do this:

```
.response.text | fromjson.title
```

Answer (score 31):

You can also do this:

```
jq -r '.response.text' | jq '.recordID'
```