# Pull value in jq with escaped vars

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON that I am trying to process.
I am using jq and can't for my life get the required output.

I have a simple eg below,

```
{
    "message" :"{ \"foo\": \"42\", \"bar\": \"less interesting data\"}"

}
```

My Build Up

```
jq '."message"

{
   "message" :{"foo": "42", "bar": "less interesting data"}
}
```

gives

```
{
  "foo": "42",
  "bar": "less interesting data"
}

."message"."bar"
```

gives

```
"less interesting data"
```

So

```
{
   "message" :"{"foo": "42", "bar": "less interesting data"}"
}
```

FAILS as JSON invalid

```
{
   "message" :"{\"foo\": \"42\", \"bar\": \"less interesting data\"}"
}
```

FAILS 'jq: error (at :3): Cannot index string with string "bar"
exit status 5'

I have tried a whole bunch of differing jq queries (i won't waste your time listing them)

So I would like some advice on how id get "bar" from the JSON

It's not a duplicate of convert string to JSON as this leads you to the idea of conversion. Without this question, you'd never know the answer is to use fromjson

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to json in jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340549/convert-string-to-json-in-jq)

Comment: Its not a duplicate as this leads you to the idea of conversion to a string.
Without this question, youd never know the answer is to use fromjson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `fromjson` construct to restore the strings as JSON texts. So, given the content below

```
{
    "message": "{ \"foo\": \"42\", \"bar\": \"less interesting data\" }"
}
```

all you need to do to extract `bar` is

```
jq '."message"|fromjson|.bar' file
"less interesting data"
```

To print the output without the quotes, use the `-r`/`--raw-ouput` flag which emits text in raw format. As noted in the comments `fromjson.bar` should also work as expected.